# Spawn Process/Run Executable on Web Server

Tags: php, python, http, webserver, process

I am looking to run a process (for example an instance of python) on a web server. How do I initiate this via http request? For example, a user arrives on my page, I want to initiate a python instance on the web server that can be accessed via ajax requests. For now, I just want to focus on the initiation of the process though.

To be clear, and I failed to make this clear - sorry, I wanted to initiate (using php) a python process on the server and then send execution commands to it. Also, I found an answer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mod_python`](http://www.modpython.org/) on Apache. Stick a Python file in your [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#documentroot). Blammo.. You have Python executing on your web server.

Comment: That sounds über interesting!

Comment: Turns out proc_open for php doesn't keep a persistent process open - it only is accessible by that individual page.